# Outlook opens in old version in chrome headless mode. How to resolve it in Selenium C#

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless, outlook-web-app

While running chrome in headless mode outlook open as in the older version

[image]

It should open with the latest outlook web mode

[image]

Note: When we run in chrome browser (with head) it opens the outlook with latest UI

Is there anything should i add in ChromeArgument?

Answer (score 0):

Headless mode user agent is:
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) **HeadlessChrome**/109.0.5414.120 Safari/537.36

Whereas the real Chrome user agent is:
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) **Chrome**/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36

we need to override the chrome argument while initializing the chromedriver

```
chromeOptions.Add("--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36");
```